# Content refresh issue on Jquery ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax

i use the below jquery ajax request. On success, the "ajaxRenderSuccess" function may last from 500ms to 1200ms, therefore before running this function i highlight a new step in my UI (a kind of progression bar): i just remove ui-state-highlight class from the previous step ("renderingPhase"), and add it on the final step ("outputPhase").

All works as expected, except i never see my outputPhase highlighted, even if ajaxRenderSuccess function lasts more than 1 second: it seems it absolutely wants execute the whole "success" ajax event before refreshing the page?

If i display alert('output phase highlighted') to temporize just between the addClass and ajaxRenderSuccess call, then it works the final step is correctly highlighted...

Is it a known issue, and/or a normal behavior? What could i do to force display refresh within this "success" jquery event?

thanks!

```
   var self = this;
   jQuery.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: renderingURL,
       contentType:"text/html; charset=UTF-8",
       success: function (respJSON){
            jQuery( "#"+self.request.namespace+"renderingPhase" ).removeClass('ui-state-highlight'); 
            jQuery( "#"+self.request.namespace+"outputPhase" ).addClass('ui-state-highlight');      
            self.ajaxRenderSuccess(respJSON);
       }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The function seems completely fine, so probably there is something wrong with the selector.

Try doing a

```
console.log(jQuery( "#"+self.request.namespace+"outputPhase" ));
```

and see if the element is selected correctly in firebug (or similar).

Could be a class= in the tag instead of id=, but the aforementioned log will tell you if this is the problem. Also keep the debugger window open for any errors

Comment: Thanks for suggestions. I tried console.log(jQuery( "#"+self.request.namespace+"outputPhase" )), it returns the expected outputPhase button, this is not a selector issue, since if i temporize with an alert box my button is correctly highlighted. I did not see any error  in chrome console or firebug